# Axios handle 307

Tags: javascript, api, axios, client

Atm i have an app that does api requests client-side.
I do an api request to a certain URL but it provides me with 307 redirect and then axios doesn’t  follow, it just gets the empty data of the not redirected url.

Is there a way for axios to handle 307?
(Tested on python, worked perfectly and followed the redirect) due to them being server-side and client-side tho guessing there is a difference.